# why wont react class print json unless props

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to react and trying to understand how to print json values to dom.

this works:

```
var C = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return <p>{this.props.data[0].product}</p>
      }
    });

    var data = [
     {
      product:"Hello",
      quantiy:2
     },
     {
      product:"two",
      quantiy:4
     },
     {
      product:"three",
      quantiy:3
     }
    ]
    React.render(<C data={data}/>, document.body);
```

but when i try this it doesnt work why?

```
var C = React.createClass({
    var data = [
     {
      product:"Hello",
      quantiy:2
     },
     {
      product:"two",
      quantiy:4
     },
     {
      product:"three",
      quantiy:3
     }
    ]
      render: function() {
        return <p>{this.data[0].product}</p>
      }
    });


    React.render(<C />, document.body);
```

I have created an array and called this.data[0].product but it doesnt work

Comment: Your second example is not even valid JavaScript...

Comment: oh so 'this' is only called on functions in same class not objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you write `this.data` but `data` is not declared on `this`.

try

```
    var C = React.createClass({
        data: [
            {
                product: "Hello",
                quantiy: 2
            },
            {
                product: "two",
                quantiy: 4
            },
            {
                product: "three",
                quantiy: 3
            }
        ],

        render: function () {
            return <p>{this.data[0].product}</p>;
        }
    });
```

or

```
    var C = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            var data = [
                {
                    product: "Hello",
                    quantiy: 2
                },
                {
                    product: "two",
                    quantiy: 4
                },
                {
                    product: "three",
                    quantiy: 3
                }
            ];

            return <p>{data[0].product}</p>;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use state

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: [
     {
      product:"Hello",
      quantiy:2
     },
     {
      product:"two",
      quantiy:4
     },
     {
      product:"three",
      quantiy:3
     }
    ]};
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.data[1].product}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Using the component `state` is possible but is useless here. Adding a state on a component must not be seen as a way to attach data to it. When the state is useless, It is a bad pratice that can prevent to use [react stateless components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions)